# Allow date less than minDate in flatpickr

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I have the following code:

```
if (setToToday) {
  this.flatpickr({
      minDate: 'today',
      defaultDate: new Date( $(this).attr("date")),
  });
} else {
    flatpickr(this).setDate(new Date( $(this).attr("date") ));
}
```

Now what I would like to do is to show the user a date value less than `today` if the `attr(date)` is lesser today. Suppose today is `2021-03-03` and the previously selected value was `2021-02-02`, I would like to allow the user to select that previous date or any date from today. Nothing in between. How can I do that in flatpickr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’d like to make certain dates unavailable for selection, there are multiple methods of doing so.

1. Disabling specific date
2. Disabling a date range
3. Disabling dates using a function

**Disabling specific dates**

```
{
    disable: ["2025-01-30", "2025-02-21", "2025-03-08", new Date(2025, 4, 9) ],
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
}
```

**Disabling range(s) of dates:**

```
{
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
    disable: [
        {
            from: "2025-04-01",
            to: "2025-05-01"
        },
        {
            from: "2025-09-01",
            to: "2025-12-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Disabling dates by a function:**

```
{
    "disable": [
        function(date) {
            // return true to disable
            return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);

        }
    ],
    "locale": {
        "firstDayOfWeek": 1 // start week on Monday
    }
}
```

[Refer to the official documentation for more](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/)